# Is it ever safe to use a reference in place of a pointer with a function called across an FFI boundary?

Tags: pointers, rust, ffi

I've gathered that references are not the same as pointers, and in fact they have some pretty important distinctions, such as alignment guarantees, null-ness guarantees, and aliasing guarantees, and as such, if you have a function intended to be used across an FFI boundary that takes a raw pointer, you should typically use a raw pointer in the signature to avoid potential issues.

However, are there any situations in which it would be acceptable to use a reference (or something like `Option<&T>`) in such a function signature? For example, if you are binding an API with a well defined spec that says something like "`*T` must be valid or it's undefined behavior", could you still run into issues with a reference in place of a pointer in a signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always safe to use plain references instead of pointers, as long as the pointer behaves as the reference would. As the [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#interoperability-with-foreign-code) says:

> **References can safely be assumed to be non-nullable pointers directly
> to the type**. However, breaking the borrow checking or mutability rules
> is not guaranteed to be safe, so prefer using raw pointers (*) if
> that's needed because the compiler can't make as many assumptions
> about them.

Also, as the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#pointers-and-references-layout) says:

> Pointers and references have the same layout.

Problems *will* arise if you have a shared reference `&T` and the function behind FFI does *not* treat this as a `const *`, that is, mutate the `T` including *anything* that aliases with `&T` (e.g. a field in a `U` that can be reached via `&T`). That is [because](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html)

> If you have a reference &T, then normally in Rust the compiler
> performs optimizations based on the knowledge that &T points to
> immutable data. Mutating that data, **for example** through an alias or by
> transmuting an &T into an &mut T, is considered undefined behavior.

That is, the compiler will always assume by the mere existence of `&T` that `T` can't change (not accounting for `UnsafeCell`). In practical terms, the compiler will assume that the FFI-function will *not* change `T` if a `&T` exists as an argument. As advised by the nomicon, it's good practice to prefer `*const T` and `*mut T` over mere references, because the compiler can reason about where that raw pointer came from (e.g. it will catch if you try to derive a `*mut T` from a `&T`). It is therefore also strongly advised that your FFI definitions are const-correct; e.g. a function that pretends to take `const *` but actually modifies that argument could be called with `&T` or a  `*const T` without the compiler being able to catch this.

When it comes to individual types, the interoperability is up to the type itself. The nomicon has [a whole section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#interoperability-with-foreign-code) about this. In general:

> Rust guarantees that the layout of a struct is compatible with the
> platform's representation in C only if the #[repr(C)] attribute is
> applied to it.

This only gives you the guarantee that the type layout as one would write it in C will be the same as it is in Rust, though. You can't generally assume that the Rust-type will *behave* as it would in C. However, in the specific example of `Option` or `Box`, the Rust implementation in `std` [does provide such guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization); also see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/index.html#representation) and [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout) (`Box<T> is guaranteed to be represented as a single pointer and is also ABI-compatible with C pointers (i.e. the C type T*`).

Comment: _You can't generally assume that the Rust-type will behave as it would in C._ Could you clarify what you mean here?

Comment: @YungDaVinci, e.g. unless specified you can't simply assume that `Foo::Option1` will be represented as zero (and `Foo::Option2` as `1`); it just may "seem" to work. Also, the types may have stronger guarantees than what C can enforce. For example, `NonZeroU32` is just a `u32` internally, but setting the equivalent `long` (or whatever) to 0 in C-land causes UB in Rust-land

Comment: @YungDaVinci, another example from the top of my head: `bool` will be represented as `char` in C, but C usually treats boolean as "is it zero or anything other than zero", while Rust only ever allows for `0` or `1`. You'll have to be careful to not let the C-code leak such misbehaviour into Rust-land